# How to get parse_str to recognise single-quotes on string literals?

Tags: php

How may I get parse_str to recognise delimiting single-quotes on string literals?

V5.6.13 CLI gives:

```
parse_str("a['name']=jim");
var_dump($a['name']); // Expected jim, got Undefined Index
var_dump($a["'name'"]); // Expected Undefined Index, got jim
```

I'm hoping this isn't a magic quotes curse requiring an .ini change...

Comment: `parse_str("a[name]=jim");`?

Comment: That hasn't recognised delimiting single-quotes on string literals. It has simply removed the delimiting single-quotes from the example.